# Finding best 2D curve passing by waypoints

Tags: regression, bezier-curve

For a robotic application, I am looking for a mathematical tool for finding the best curve passing by or near (up to a certain radius) from waypoints as shown below. The pink circles are obstacles that should be avoided at all cost.

I looked at NURBS or Bezier curves, but most of the examples I found do not intersect with waypoints.

[image]

The criteria for finding the curve are:

- Minimum distance
- Maximum curvature (or tangential velocity)
- Avoid obstacles.

Our initial approach was to use A* algorithm to find the shortest path between two points. Then keypoints are identified from the yellow curve and a smooth, continuous curve is computed. It is quite easy to draw such curve by hand, but I currently found no reliable tool or mathematical approach to automate the process.

[image]

What would be a good mathematical approach for such problem?

Comment: Can you write an objective function that gives a score (a scalar) for a given parametric curve? Maybe this is a starting point as this function might be used in a minimization scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Constructing a curve that passes through your “way points” is fairly simple. For example, you could construct a spline curve that interpolates these points. Look up the term “spline interpolation”, or start [here](https://pages.mtu.edu/%7Eshene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/INT-APP/CURVE-INT-global.html).

Regarding your constraints on distance (arclength) and curvature, they are contradictory, and you’ll need to find a way to balance them. The shortest curve is a piecewise linear one, with a straight line between each consecutive pair of way points, but this obviously has infinite curvature at the way points.

I suspect that what you’re really trying to do is minimize the travel time of the robot. To do this, you have to vary both the path **and** the velocity. This is a well-studied problem in robotics. Consult the literature.